# Python: what package contains the installation metadata?

Tags: python, installation, metadata

e.g., how can I find out that the executable has been installed in "/usr/bin/python" and the library files in "/usr/lib/python2.6"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[distutils.sysconfig](http://docs.python.org/distutils/apiref.html#module-distutils.sysconfig) is the module that "provides access to Python’s low-level configuration information".  The [get_python_lib](http://docs.python.org/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.sysconfig.get_python_lib) function, in particular, gives "the directory for either the general or platform-dependent library installation", depending on its arguments.

However, `sys.executable` is not exposed by said `sysconfig` module -- it's only in the `sys` module.

Comment: Thanks Alex!  It looks like get_python_lib(1,1) is just what I need.  Calling with the default parms returns the site_packages directory.

Answer (score 1):

You want the `sys` module:

```
>>> print sys.executable
/usr/bin/python
>>> print sys.path
['', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python26.zip',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-darwin', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-mac', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-old', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload', 
'/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/wx-2.8-mac-unicode']
```

Comment: not quite... I'm looking for where the installer installed the system libraries, not the system libraries which are on the path.